# Helpdesk URL in Lync Attendee

Tags: windows, lync, ms-office-communicator

I work as a Lync Admin for a company that has a mixed Lync Client and Lync Attendee environment. We have a helpdesk environment set up for all of our clients pushed out using the Cs-ConferencingPolicy InternalHelpdeskURL and ExternalHelpdeskURL properties, but this does not seem to be carrying over to the Attendee clients.

Where is the Helpdesk URL set for the attendee? Is it customizable?

Thanks in advance.